# How to disable the docked Finder monitor pop-up on OS X?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, finder, activity-monitor

Attached is the screen shot of annoying screen monitor round cornered box, not sure what thats called. I dont know how it appeared!!! I wanna disable it. The Command+option+escape window doesn't show the Force Quit button for that 'Finder', instead its Relaunch.

[image]

Edit: Its called **Voice Over**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have activated VoiceOver mode. To disable either press <kbd>Cmd-F5</kbd> or go to System Preferences -> Accessibility -> Voice Over and turn it off there.